# Why only id column is shown in migration file when I create model in Python?

Tags: python, django-models, migration

from django.db import models

```
class Town(models.Model):

     name: models.CharField(max_length=70,unique=True)
     country: models.CharField(max_length=30,unique=True)

     class Meta:
         pass
```

This is my model Town whith two attributes: name and country. When I create a migration in the initial_0001.py file only id column is shown

from django.db import migrations, models

```
class Migration(migrations.Migration):

    initial = True

dependencies = [
]

operations = [
    migrations.CreateModel(
        name='Town',
        fields=[
            ('id', models.BigAutoField(auto_created=True, primary_key=True, serialize=False, verbose_name='ID')),
        ],
    ),
]
```

What kind of problem could it be?

Answer (score 0):

The ID-Field is always automatically generated by Django when making migrations. You can specifiy your own ID field aswell, but using an auto-incremented like this is fine for your use case.

You also might want to get rid of the `unique=True`, as it would prevent adding multiple towns from the same country.

Create your model like this and redo your migration process:

```
class Town(models.Model):

     name = models.CharField(max_length=70)
     country = models.CharField(max_length=30)
```

When you have **'no changes detected'** when making migrations, I usually follow these steps:

First, Delete migrations folder in project.

Then delete django-migration entries in your Database with this query:

```
DELETE from django_migrations WHERE app='yourAppName'
```

Then, create new folder ‘migrations” in app folder + **init**.py

Lastly, redo the migration process:

```
py manage.py makemigrations
py manage.py migrate --run-syncdb
```

Comment: I am familiar with the id column. The problem  is that the name and country column are not shown in the migration file 0001_initial. Also if I make change in the class for instance if I add other property for example population when I tried to make  makemigrations command I recieve message no changes detected. I want to notice that that i register my app in INSRALLED_APPS

Comment: I added information about fixing the migration

Comment: I have followed your steps but without result.Model is recognized because table town is created. But the props inside the class name and country missing.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem, and this solved it. Hope it helps.

1. Instead of : it should be =
2. You also need to provide a default value for all the previous rows that were created
3. Then run python manage.py makemigrations
4. Run python manage.py migrate

```
    class Town(models.Model):
    
         name = models.CharField(max_length=70,unique=True, default='')
         country = models.CharField(max_length=30,unique=True, default='')
    
         class Meta:
             pass
```